# How to pass token number in httpheader field?

Tags: ios

> I get a token number form login api response and i need to send this token in the url with http header field. please look at my response first which i get from login api.

```
{"token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6ImpvaG4uc21pdGhAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiaWQiOiI1NzFkYzI3NmU0YjA1NjVmNTcwZjM2ZGQiLCJpYXQiOjE0NjMwMzY2Nzd9.3p2lXjOvQ-iIJZWr4GwuHCYf9VCDZbb3l9O1a8d7Eqs","data":{"name":"John Smith","role":"driver"},"message":"success"}
```

> now i need to send this toke in another url and i saved it in a string. please look at the code for header field.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

token = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"Accesstoken"];
NSLog(@"Accesstoken %@", token);



NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://qa.networc.in:1336/api/dispatcher/rideHistory/:page"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL      cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:20.0f];

//Specify method of request(Get or Post)
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

//Pass some default parameter(like content-type etc.)
[theRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[theRequest setValue:@"application/json; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

//Now pass your own parameter

[theRequest setValue:token forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
NSLog(@"req %@", theRequest);
NSURLResponse *theResponse = NULL;
NSError *theError = NULL;
NSData *theResponseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&theResponse error:&theError];

//Now you can create a NSDictionary with NSJSONSerialization
NSDictionary *dataDictionaryResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:theResponseData options:0 error:&theError];
NSLog(@"url to send request= %@",theURL);
NSLog(@"%@",dataDictionaryResponse);

 }
```

Comment: whats your token  request type

Comment: token request type is GET

Comment: are you get the token value in log

Comment: in here ypu got the output NSLog(@"Accesstoken %@", token);

Comment: yes i get the token value from login api response and now i need to send it in header field

Comment: just wait , i will check ...

Comment: i got the output of     `message = "No token provided.";`, check your token is valid means correct or not

Comment: ok sir let me check this but it should be ok because it comes form api

Comment: problem in token bro, your code is fine conform once with your back end developer

Comment: sir i am getting token dynamically form login api and the same sent in headeer

Answer (score 0):

Try This For Get ->

```
 NSString *stringURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://qa.networc.in:1336/api/dispatcher/rideHistory/:page"];


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringURL]];

[request addValue:@"token" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error: nil];
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData
                                                     options:kNilOptions                                                     error:nil];
NSLog(@"--->%@",son);
```

Post->

```
    NSError *error;

NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:nil delegateQueue:nil];
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:[ NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://qa.networc.in:1336/api/dispatcher/rideHistory/:page"]];;
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:60.0];
[request addValue:@"token" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSMutableDictionary *mapData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];//
[mapData setValue:@"Anyname" forKey:@"useremail"];
[mapData setValue:@"Anypwd" forKey:@"password"];
NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:mapData options:0 error:&error];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];


NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)

                                     {

                                         if(error == nil)
                                         {
                                             NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                             NSLog(@"Data>>>> = %@",text);
                                         }

                                     }];
[postDataTask resume];
```

Comment: what should be api key in my case, a parameter?